# N2CMS while uploadin or updateing any files

Tags: n2cms

Server Error in '/' Application.
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (ctl00$Content$ie$Text=". After setting this value, you can then disable request validation by setting validateRequest="false" in the Page directive or in the  configuration section. However, it is strongly recommended that your application explicitly check all inputs in this case. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=153133.

Comment: I see you have asked 21 questions and not accepted any answers. Why?

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are running N2CMS under ASP.NET 4.0. Please add following line into your web.config in order to remove some of default security obstacles that were not present in 2.0

```
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```